# Improving performance of a loop with succeeding string replacements?

Tags: r

I have (html-)texts and I want to change the `&ouml;` things to real characters like ä, ü, ö, and so on because otherwise the xml-package does not accept it.

So I wrote a little function which cycles through a replacement table ([link1](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp), [link2](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp)) and does replace special character by special character by sp... the function looks like this (only looonger):

```
html.charconv <- function(text){
    replacer <- matrix(c(
    "Á",    "&Aacute;",
    "á",    "&aacute;",
    "Â",    "&Acirc;",
    "â",    "&acirc;",
    "´",    "&acute;"
    )
    ,ncol=2,byrow=T)

    for(i in 1:length(replacer[,1])){
        text <- str_replace_all(text,replacer[i,2],replacer[i,1])
    }
    text
}
```

**How might I speed this up?** I thought about vectorization but did not come with any helping solution because for each cycle the result of the last cycle is its starting point.

Comment: why do you need performance? your loop (5 steps) is really slow or it is called in another process?

Comment: This is an minimal example; I would not ask if it were not important; The actual loop entails 105 replacements and is applied to more than 36'000 html-files all of considerably length. So things can take a while.

Comment: I asked to have more info about the process. did you try parallel ? i.e    input.data <- llply(input.files, html.charconv, .parallel=TRUE)

Comment: The expensive operation in this algorithm is going to be `<-`. I would start by modifying the loop to first do a `grep` to establish if the search string exists, then run `gsub` and assign the results only when necessary. Also, since speed is important to you, I suggest getting to grips with `gsub` - `str_replace_all` is simply a wrapper around `gsub` and will slow things down.

Comment: PS. My first instinct was to use `chartr` but I couldn't get it to work in this case.

Comment: Hardware is: Windows7 64 Bit enterpr., Intel-dual-core E5700 3GHz, 8GB RAM 1333MHz, my pw is 123456

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a significant speedup by constructing your function a bit different, and forget about the text tools. Basically you :

1. split the character string
2. match the characters you want and replace them by the new characters
3. paste everything together again

You can do that with following function :

```
html.fastconv <- function(x,old,new){
    xs <- strsplit(x,"&|;")
    old <- gsub("&|;","",old)
    xs <- lapply(xs,function(i){
        id <- match(i,old,0L)
        i[id!=0] <- new[id]
        return(i)
    })
    sapply(xs,paste,collapse="")
}
```

This works as :

```
> sometext <- c("&Aacute;dd som&aacute; le&Acirc;tter&acirc; acute problems et&acute; cetera",
+  "&Aacute;dd som&aacute; le&Acirc;tter&acirc; acute p ..." ... [TRUNCATED] 

> newchar <- c("Á","á","Â","â","´")

> oldchar <- c("&Aacute;","&aacute;","&Acirc;","&acirc;","&acute;")
> html.fastconv(sometext,oldchar,newchar)
[1] "Ádd somá leÂtterâ acute problems et´ cetera" "Ádd somá leÂtterâ acute problems et´ cetera"
```

For the record, some benchmarking :

```
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(html.fastconv(sometext,oldchar,newchar),html.charconv(sometext),
     columns=c("test","elapsed","relative"),
     replications=1000) 
                                       test elapsed relative
2                   html.charconv(sometext)    0.79    5.643
1 html.fastconv(sometext, oldchar, newchar)    0.14    1.000
```

Comment: ah ow, I need more coffee apparently

Comment: Fixed. And regarding the matrix: By getting that one out of the function, you don't have to re-assign it every time you call the function. There's no need for that. I guess OP is smart enough to figure out how to adapt the code in such a way that he can pass a matrix. Or to just do `fastconv(sometext,mat[,1],mat[,2])` or something to that extent.

Comment: Similar technique did indeed

Comment: I do not totally understand what you did, but it looks much much faster than my code applying it to my html-files, about 40 times faster.

Comment: @PeterM Actually the solution by John should be faster than mine. Did you try that one as well? And the Rcpp solution is definitely way faster, but then you need to understand a bit of C++ as well.

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun, here is a version based on `Rcpp`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector rcpp_conv( 
    CharacterVector text, CharacterVector old , CharacterVector new_){

    int n  = text.size() ;
    int nr = old.size() ;

    std::string buffer, current_old, current_new ;
    size_t pos, current_size ; 
    CharacterVector res(n) ;

    for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        buffer = text[i] ;
        for( int j=0; j<nr; j++){
             current_old = old[j] ;
             current_size = current_old.size() ;
             current_new = new_[j] ;
             pos = 0 ;   
             pos = buffer.find( current_old ) ;
             while( pos != std::string::npos ){
                 buffer.replace( 
                     pos, current_size, 
                     current_new
                 ) ;
                 pos = buffer.find( current_old ) ;
             }
        }
        res[i] = buffer ;
    }
    return res ;
}
```

For which I get quite a further performance gain:

```
> microbenchmark(
+     html.fastconv( sometext,oldchar,newchar),
+     html.fastconvJC(sometext, oldchar, newchar),
+     rcpp_conv( sometext, oldchar, newchar)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                                         expr    min      lq   median      uq
1   html.fastconv(sometext, oldchar, newchar) 97.588 99.9845 101.4195 103.072
2 html.fastconvJC(sometext, oldchar, newchar) 19.945 23.3060  25.8110  28.134
3       rcpp_conv(sometext, oldchar, newchar)  4.047  5.1555   6.2340   9.275
      max
1 256.061
2  40.647
3  25.763
```

Here is an implementation based on the `Rcpp::String` feature, available from `Rcpp >= 0.10.2`:

```
class StringConv{
public:
    typedef String result_type ;
    StringConv( CharacterVector old_, CharacterVector new__): 
        nr(old_.size()), old(old_), new_(new__){}

    String operator()(String text) const {
        for( int i=0; i<nr; i++){
            text.replace_all( old[i], new_[i] ) ;
        }     
        return text ;
    }

private:
    int nr ;
    CharacterVector old ;
    CharacterVector new_ ;
} ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector test_sapply_string( 
   CharacterVector text, CharacterVector old , CharacterVector new_
){
   CharacterVector res = sapply( text, StringConv( old, new_ ) ) ;
   return res ;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that 36,000 file read and writes is your bottleneck and the way you code in R can't help much with that.  Some things just take a while.  Your function looks like it will work right, just let it run.  There are a few small improvements you could make.

```
replacer <- matrix(c(
    "Á",    "&Aacute;",
    "á",    "&aacute;",
    "Â",    "&Acirc;",
    "â",    "&acirc;",
    "´",    "&acute;"
    )
    ,ncol=2, byrow=T)

html.fastconvJC <- function(x,old,new){
    n <- length(new)
    s <- x #make a copy cause I'm scared of scoping in R :)
    for (i in 1:n) s <- gsub(old[i], new[i], s, fixed = TRUE)
    s
    }

# borrowing the strings from Joris Meys
benchmark(html.fastconvJC(sometext, replacer[,2], replacer[,1]),
      html.charconv(sometext), columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"),
      replications=1000)

                                                     test elapsed relative
2                                 html.charconv(sometext)   0.727    17.31
1 html.fastconvJC(sometext, replacer[, 2], replacer[, 1])   0.042     1.00
```

And they increased speed more than I expected.  Note that a huge part of that speedup is making `fixed = TRUE`, otherwise Joris Meys answer comes in about the same speed.

If this doesn't get your far in overall speed you know your bottleneck is elsewhere, likely file reads and writes.  Unless you have solid state or RAID drives, running this in parallel isn't going to speed anything up and might just slow it down.

Comment: I'm quite amazed by the speedup as well. Nice thinking

Comment: I think it's good to have both answers because the general technique of `strsplit` does sometimes work phenomenally well (like if the replace was reversed :) ).  I really didn't expect this one to be much faster than yours, maybe about the same.

Comment: You avoid a split and a paste, so there's the gain.

Comment: I tried `fixed = TRUE` in yours and it's a bit faster than this.  There might be scaling differences with longer passages of text though.

Comment: Doing a benchmark with 100 of my html-files my function takes about 50s; John's takes about 4s; and Joris' about 1.5s. Congratulation guys, thats impressive :-) although I do not know why my benchmarking and Joris benchmarking differ that much.

Comment: Concerning Hardware: Would be nice to have all the stuff but this is sadly not an option :-(

Comment: As I indicated above, Joris and I's answers will scale differently with file size.  The toy example I used isn't really a good test.  The assignments of a large file in mine should slow things a bit.  That could be overcome a number of ways (e.g. don't be afraid of scoping like I am, test for presence of the item before gsub).  The regex method might win afterall with those changes.  But for a toy example I'd never see benefits.

Answer (score -1):

I will try with plyr :

```
input.data <- llply(input.files, html.charconv, .parallel=TRUE)
```

Comment: I will consider that for reading the file, though no input of files is involved in this example. It is only about the replacement of 'characters'.

Comment: Using Joris function the whole process of reading in data and preparing takes now 5 instead of 59 seconds - for 100 files. So, reading files might be an issue, but the faster string replacements helped a lot.