# Replacing parts of a list

Tags: string, r

Is there an easy way to replace a sub-list of strings in a character vector with another list of strings? something like

```
gsub(c("a","b"),c("z","y"),a)
```

or

```
replace(a,c("a","b"),c("z","y"))
```

neither of which unfortunately work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop using `gsub` would suffice and will probably perform just fine in most cases:

```
a <- c("x","y")
b <- c("a","b")
vec <- "xy12"

 mgsub <- function(pattern,replacement,x,...){
    for (i in seq_along(pattern)){
        x <- gsub(pattern = pattern[i],replacement = replacement[i],x,...)
    }
    x
 }

> mgsub(a,b,vec)
[1] "ab12"
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are just replacing single characters, then `chartr` might just be what you are looking for :

```
> chartr( "ab", "zy", "abababa")
[1] "zyzyzyz"
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581465/improving-performance-of-a-loop-with-succeeding-string-replacements) might also be of interest.

Comment: thanks @romainfrancois, a good answer and a function I hadnt used before. I've chosen the other answer because that is the solution I'm going with.

Answer (score 0):

I could've sworn there was a recursive apply in R, and there is, but it does something very different.

Anyhow, here's one:

```
#' Iteratively (recursively) apply a function to its own output
#' @param X a vector of first arguments to be passed in
#' @param FUN a function taking a changing (x) and an initial argument (init)
#' @param init an argument to be "worked on" by FUN with parameters x[1], x[2], etc.
#' @return the final value, of the same type as init
#' @example
#' vec <- "xy12"
#' replacementPairs <- list( c("x","a"), c("y","b") )
#' iapply( replacementPairs , FUN=function(repvec,x) {
#'   gsub(repvec[1],repvec[2],x)
#' }, init=vec )
iapply <- function(X, FUN, init, ...) {
  res <- init
  for(x in X) {
    res <- FUN(x, res, ...)
  }
  res
}
```

The example returns `"ab12"`.